# Слово "каракули"

Tags: этимология

Слово "каракули" действительно имеет тюркское происхождение, как мне слышится, или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, действительно, считается что слово *каракули* произошло от  тюркского *каракол* — сложения *кара* "черная" и *кол* "рука" ("дурная рука" > "плохой почерк").

Comment: А слово "каракуль" происходит из того же источника? Оно явно тоже тюркское, только вторая часть "кюль" (u умляут), наверное, не связана с "кул" - "рука". Тем более, что есть слово "кёль" - "озеро" (транскрипция условная).  
Я заметила (при изучении татарского), что в тюркских языках многие слова отличаются только произношением гласных (мягко или твердо и т.п.).

Comment: Да, тоже из тюркского. От  Кара-Куль (оазис около Бухары, где начали выводить соответствующую породу овец),  кара "черная" и кул "озеро"

Comment: >в тюркских языках многие слова отличаются только произношением гласных (мягко или твердо и т.п.).  
  
Естественно. Узбеки с татарами почти свободно общаются. Не говоря уж о турках.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы скорей подумала, что это от слова каракуль, вроде как в "каракулевая шапка", такие же "завитушки" :) 
"кара" - чёрный, "куль/гуль" - цветок, роза

Comment: так каракуль и есть то самое предполагаемое тюркское слово. Только там кул - озеро, не "гюль". Название породы происходит от топонима Кара-Кул - Черное озеро (Около Бухары). Другие объяснения - вторичны. Но в целом объяснение Ларf под сомнение не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

А еще caracol - это улитка по-испански.

Answer (score -3):

Ошибаетесь, Русский язык это язык образов.И многие слова в нем возникают просто от образа.Например слово заковыка или колдо*бина, вообще нашей дворовой диалектике(фене) равных нет, и как люди понимают друг друга порой сложно объяснить, у нас очень важна интонация и ситуация в которой произнесено слово.Но есть и такое долбить-услышал человек звук от удара и вот так вот воспроизвел, кому то услышалось бах,кому то дун-дун,  и тд и пошло Долбарь(дурак)и тд.Иногда что то видишь то что вызывает эмоцию и брякнешь то что на ум придет, в этом случае я думаю увидел человек непонятно что нарисованное и в голове отложился образ КРивизны-вот он и сказал что за каракули.В этом отношении и слово трактор нам выводят из другого языка, а вполне возможно что просто человек услышал тр тр тр тр и сказал трактор!